# evaluates short texts in semantic net similarity

Tags: python, nlp, semantics, similarity, sentence-similarity

I have a program that evaluates short texts. It gives an original text and is transferred to a semantic network.
Then it is compared to several short texts that are also converted into a semantic net.
The similarity between the original text and the rest of the texts is measured using the similarity of meaning to the sentences.
How can I work these steps in Python and what are the libraries that can be used?
Are there ready-made codes that I can use in my work?
Please Help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure to read the guidelines for posting questions. As a rule of thumb, it is customary to share code and data that might help the community answer your question. Also, shre what you have attemptet so far to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For measuring semantic similarity between short texts, I'd recommend [Sentence-Transformers](https://www.sbert.net/docs/quickstart.html). See this example from the documentation:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
model = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')

sentences = ['A man is eating food.',
          'A man is eating a piece of bread.',
          'The girl is carrying a baby.',
          'A man is riding a horse.',
          'A woman is playing violin.',
          'Two men pushed carts through the woods.',
          'A man is riding a white horse on an enclosed ground.',
          'A monkey is playing drums.',
          'Someone in a gorilla costume is playing a set of drums.'
          ]

#Encode all sentences
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)

#Compute cosine similarity between all pairs
cos_sim = util.pytorch_cos_sim(embeddings, embeddings)

#Add all pairs to a list with their cosine similarity score
all_sentence_combinations = []
for i in range(len(cos_sim)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(cos_sim)):
        all_sentence_combinations.append([cos_sim[i][j], i, j])

#Sort list by the highest cosine similarity score
all_sentence_combinations = sorted(all_sentence_combinations, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

print("Top-5 most similar pairs:")
for score, i, j in all_sentence_combinations[0:5]:
    print("{} \t {} \t {:.4f}".format(sentences[i], sentences[j], cos_sim[i][j]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the library sentence_transformers does not work on a Python version .  Is there another way to work, knowing that I want the similarity results to be numerical values

Comment: Which python version are you using? Cant you update/downgrade your python or create a virtual environment with the right python version? Im afraid you will have problems with many libraries when you're using a very old/too new python version and its probably worth creating a virtual env.

Comment: Use the version 3.8.5

Comment: mh.. the documentation says "We recommend Python 3.6 or higher". https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/tree/v0.3.9 I'm using it with python 3.7 and it works fine. I would recommend using a virtual environment with a lower version of python if it doesn't work with yours. it's often good not to use the very latest version, because some libraries don't support it yet (although 3.8 is not that new anymore).  here is how to create a virtual environment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/venv.html